# grunt cucumberjs multiple parallel runs

Tags: gruntjs, cucumberjs

I am trying to run cucumberjs tests via grunt for a matrix of browserstack capabilities.

The matrix is configured "grunt" normally (qcuberbatch is the local grunt task definition):

```
grunt.initConfig
    qcumberbatch:
        options:
            steps: 'src/features/integration/steps'
            tags: '~@ShouldFail'
            browserstack:
                'browserstack.user' : process.env.BS_USER
                'browserstack.key' : process.env.BS_ACCESS_KEY
                'browserstack.tunnel' : 'true' # This was the secret!

            matrix: [
                browser: 'firefox'
                browser_version: '26.0'
                os: 'Windows'
                os_version : '7',
            ,
                browser : 'IE',
                browser_version : '9.0',
                os : 'Windows',
                os_version : '7',
                resolution : '1024x768'
            ]
            hub: "http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub"

        local:
            files:
                src: ['src/features/integration/*']
            options:
                hub: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
                matrix: ['firefox']

        browserstack:
            files:
                src: ['src/features/integration/*']

        failing:
            files:
                src: ['src/features/integration/*']
            options:
                tags: '@ShouldFail'
```

The default options has it running against browserstack using firefox and IE on Windows 7, with local tests overriding browserstack to use a local selenium webdriver hub.

The cucumber world is set up with a constructor taking the capabilities object:

```
module.exports = class World
    ###
    Create a new world, assuming firefox capabilities.

    @param {string} browser property name from the `webdriver.Capabilities`
        list.
    ###
    constructor: (capabilities = {browserName: "firefox"})->
        @driver = new webdriver.Builder().
            usingServer(process.env.SELENIUM_HUB).
            withCapabilities(capabilities).build()

        @driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000)
```

The problem, when running this from grunt, is that cucumberjs has no programmatic interface (that I see). Without the ability to configure which of several capabilities blocks to load at runtime, what should I do to communicate the capabilities between the cucumberjs run and grunt?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with your solution and a JSON object as I suggested.

However, if you're interested in a more programmatic approach, you can quite easily instantiate Cucumber runtimes. The CLI source is pretty straightforward and it's a good example of how to invoke Cucumber from your code. See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli.js.

Comment: I had considered tying in to the CLI, but that will require having the capabilities in a file in the required step files. From my view, the Support Code loader is problematic in only loading code from file paths, rather than allowing the Runtime to pass in an object with step definitions. However, that has a variety of architectural issues in other pages. Probably out of the scope of this question.

If I posted this as an enhancement for 0.6 on the github, would you be interested in altering the API?

Comment: Of course, we can improve on it. Have you checked how we inject support code in a browser context? That could help. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/example/example.js#L80

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't seen that. I'll take a look and post something.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Write a file to a known location in the grunt file with a blob of ALL the capabilities. Then, start several cucumberjs runs, using a process environment variable to tell the world which capability to use from the blob.

I don't like this, as it involves creating temp files per run, etc. I would much prefer to find a way to use cucumberjs programmatically when configuring the World object.

Comment: Extending on that idea, what about passing the capabilities as JSON in the env var? Then parse that JSON string in your World and get your object back.